# Return an unset value in value converter

Tags: mvvmcross

Using a value converter in WPF, you can return something like `DependecyProperty.UnsetValue` or `Binding.DoNothing` as special values to say leave the binding alone. Is there a similar mechanism in MVVMCross?

To be more specific about what I'm trying to do, is I have a view model property that is a three-state enum that I need to bind to 3 binary controls. So I thought I could bind each of the controls to a `MyEnum` -> `bool` converter that will have a conversion parameter set to the value of the converter and in the `Convert` method it will return true if the `MyEnum` state is equal to the parameter and false otherwise. So far so good. But I want this binding to be two-way, so I need to convert back. My convert back works something like this:

```
    protected override MyEnum ConvertBack(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (parameter is MyEnum)
        {
            if (value)
            {
                return (MyEnum)parameter;    // this is fine
            }
            else
            {
                return ???
            }
        }
        return base.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
    }
```

Basically, what I want to be able to do is say, if the state of my control is `true` update the bound property on my view model to be the same as the parameter, if not, leave the view model property alone.

Maybe this is the problem with using the strongly typed value converters?

Answer (score 1):

Update: UnsetValue is now available in mvvmcross - so this answer is no longer required.

---

`Binding.DoNothing`, `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue` or equivalent are currently not implemented in the MvvmCross binding system, and I don't believe there are any [feature or pull requests](http://github.com/slodge/mvvmcross/issues) currently open on this.

I'm afraid I don't really understand your example - the 'conversion parameter set to the value of the converter' and the `if (parameter is MyEnum)` snippet rather threw me - as far as I know, the parameter in windows xaml binding is a constant so I don't quite understand this example. Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Regardless, some possible approaches that might be used to assist with getting this functionality up and running in your mvx app are:

- You could throw an exception from the ValueConverter:

  - For the `Convert` direction, the binding `FallbackValue` is used if a ValueConverter fails (throws an exception)
  - For the `ConvertBack` direction, the binding does nothing if an exception is thrown (although this would unfortunately generate some trace "error" output each time)
- You could implement a custom binding for your control - something which only fires change updates when the change is one you are interested in (some custom bindings are introduced in N=28 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com which creates bindings like [BinaryEditFooTargetBinding.cs](https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-28-CustomBinding/CustomBinding.Droid/BinaryEditFooTargetBinding.cs) - it would be straight-forward to customise/filter the `TargetOnMyCountChanged` behaviour in that class)
- You could implement a custom binary control - which only fires change updates when the change is one you are interested in (for various platforms, some custom controls are introduced in N=18 to N=20 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com)
- You could implement ViewModel binary properties which mirror your View and map to your three state enum
- You could use a [ValueCombiner](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Value-Converters#tibet-valuecombiners) within the Tibet binding system - it should be relatively straight-forward to work out a combiner based on top of something like [MvxSingleValueCombiner.cs](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Combiners/MvxSingleValueCombiner.cs)

---

Alternatively/additionally, please do also consider raising a Feature and/or Pull Request for this 'do nothing' type of functionality to be included in the `TryGetValue`/`SetValue` methods in https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding/Bindings/SourceSteps/MvxSourceStep.cs#L66 - but obviously the timeline on that might be longer.

Comment: Thanks for you feedback Stuart. What I actually ended up doing was making the exposed property in my view model nullable (`MyEnum?`) and put logic in the setter that if the incoming value is null, don't update the backing field.

Comment: Oh, and on the question of the parameter, the parameter is constant, set when I set up the binding and doesn't change. The type check is just a sanity check in case I forget it, or set it to a different value. I could probably make it more generic and I might if I need the same functionality somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If anybody else encounters a similar problem, in addition to Stuart's suggestions, this is what I actually ended up doing.

In the View Model

```
    private MyEnum _selectedValue = MyEnum.SomeValue;

    public MyEnum ? SelectedValue 
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedTab;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value.HasValue)
            {
                _selectedTab = value.Value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTab);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then in my converter (now a `MvxValueConverter<MyEnum?, bool>`):

```
protected override MyEnum? ConvertBack(bool value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (parameter is MyEnum)             // this is just a sanity check
    {
        if (value)
        {
            return (MyEnum)parameter;    
        }
        else
        {
            return null
        }
    }
    return base.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture);
}
```

It's not a general solution, but it fits my immediate need.